# Android - launching My APP from Hyperlink in the email?

Tags: android, email, hyperlink

I need to wake up my application while clicking on the hyperlink that i got via email.

Any Idea? Please help on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: do you supply this hyperlink yourself? i.e., is this an email that you are generating yourself?

Comment: yeah. i will send the mail to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by using a custom URI scheme (like those `market:` urls that are handled by the Market app), or by using a custom action with the `intent:` scheme.

In both cases you should create an activity that will be started when the user clicks your link.

Let's first go through the first case:

### 1. A custom scheme

Start by declaring the activity in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name="LinkHandler">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
      android:scheme="SACPK" android:host="www.anyhost.com" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In this case, the link should look like `SACPK://www.anyhost.com/anything-goes-here`.

Your activity will receive the whole link in the intent, so you can process it and decide what to do next, based on query parameters or path:

```
public class LinkHandler extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
        // this is the URI containing your link, process it
    }
}
```

### 2. intent: scheme

This time the link should have the following format:

```
intent:#Intent;action=com.sacpk.CUSTOM_ACTION;end
```

And the intent-filter should contain a corresponding action that you will check in your activity:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="com.sacpk.CUSTOM_ACTION" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

And in your `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if ("com.sacpk.CUSTOM_ACTION".equals(getIntent().getAction()) {
         // then you really know you got here from the link
    }
}
```

The downside to this method is that you won't get any data with your intent.

This whole answer is based on commonsware's brilliant book, [The Busy Coder's Guide to Advanced Android Development](http://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid/).